# Tabularray - Alignment with \SetCell in first row

Tags: tabularray

I am stuck on a little problem of alignment.

Where did my Sellers go ? :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec = {*{3}{ X[r] } |  *{3}{ X[r] } }, 
%           colspec = { X[r] X[r] X[r] |  X[r] X[r] X[r] }, 
            width = \linewidth,
        }
         \SetCell[c=3]{c} Buyers   &  \SetCell[c=3]{c} Sellers   \\
        Ordres & Quantité & Cours & Cours & Quantité & Ordres \\ \hline
        1 & 6 & \textbf{\large 32.50} & \textbf{\large 33.50} & 4 & 1 \\
        1 & 10 & 32.40 & 33.74 & 60 & 1 \\
        1 & 138 & 32.22 & 33.75 & 700 & 2 \\        
    \end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In oppose to `\multicolumn{}{}{}` in regular `tabular` env., if you merge columns in `tabularray`, you still need to keep ampersands `&` for each column. So, in your case, the line should be: `\SetCell[c=3]{c} Buyers   && & \SetCell[c=3]{c} Sellers &&  \\`

Comment: This is an answer I should have spotted ! merci.

Comment: @Celdor Is it worth turning your comment into the answer ?

Comment: No need for that. It was a simple issue.